# Mix syntax for Boolean elements

Tags: raku

If I try to declare a Mix with Boolean components:

```
my $mix= (True => 0.3, False => 0.7).Mix;
dd $mix; # OUTPUT: «Mix $mix = ("True"=>0.3,"False"=>0.7).Mix␤»
```

They use [`Pair`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pair) syntax, which quotes automatically those *bare identifiers*. In order to avoid that, you either have to define the Pairs explicitly via Pair.new, or else use the fully qualified name.

```
my $mix= (Bool::True => 0.3, Bool::False => 0.7).Mix;
```

Is there any other way of doing that? A simpler way maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use anything that isn't seen as a bare-word.

Fully qualified names work.

```perl6
Bool::True => 1
```

The reason they work is bare-words don't have `::` in them.
So you can just prepend `::` as well.

```perl6
::True => 1
```

You can use `::(…)`

```perl6
::(True) => 1

::('True') => 1
::< True > => 1
```

You can also use `()` around `True`.

```perl6
(True) => 1
```

You could declare it backwards and use `.antipair`

```perl6
( 1 => True ).antipair

( :foo ).antipair # (Bool::True) => 'foo'
```

If you don't mind getting a sequence you can use `.invert`, or `.antipairs`

```perl6
# Seq.new( Bool::True => 1 )
( 1 => True ).invert 
( 1 => True ).antipairs

# Seq.new( Bool::True => 1, Bool::False => 2 )
( 1 => True, 2 => False ).invert
( 1 => True, 2 => False ).antipairs
```

If `True` was a subroutine instead of a term, you could append `()`

```perl6
sub True ( --> True ){}

True() => 1
```

Then there is using `Pair.new`.

```perl6
Pair.new( True, 1 )
```

Answer (score 5):

Using parens as in `(True) => 0.3` or the null pseudo-package as in `::True => 0.3` would be another option.